# Magento 2: Invalid credentials for ... aborting

Tags: magento2, composer

I was trying to use `composer install` with my project, and this message show up, please help. Thanks :)

Or please tell me how to ignore a package in composer install, i've try `composer remove magento/module-worldpay --update-with-dependencies` but doesn't work, it said that package doesn't exists in `composer.json`

[image]

> composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.4",
    "license": [
        "proprietary"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.2.4",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "sjparkinson/static-review": "~4.1",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/",
            "Magento\\ToolkitFramework\\": "dev/tools/performance-toolkit/framework/Magento/ToolkitFramework/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

> auth.json

```
{
   "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "[this is my public key on magento.marketplace.com]",
            "password": "[this is my private key on magento.marketplace.com]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you are entering wrong credentials when terminal ask you to enter (username) public key and (password)private key, make sure it

Comment: i'm not sure, but do i have to buy this `magento-worldpay` on magento.marketplace.com? because for magento 2, it take a very expensive cost.